# Convert twitter @'s and #'s to links from twitter rest api?

Tags: javascript, twitter

When I get the json from the rest api, it comes in plain text. I need to convert the @..'s and #..'s to actual links. Anyway to do that with javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume `text` to be the string containing the message. A Regular expression can easily convert the @'s and #'s to links. The `replace` function takes two arguments:

1. Search term (regular expression: `@(\S+)` means: "Match any non-whitespace after `@`, and group the non-whitespace characters `(\s+)`)
2. Replacement. The `$1` refers to the grouped match at 1.

Code:

```
text = text.replace(/@(\S+)/g, '<a href="https://twitter.com/#!/$1">@$1</a>')
           .replace(/#(\S+)/g, '<a href="https://twitter.com/#!/%23$1">#$1</a>');
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a good function posted [here](http://roadha.us/2011/03/create-anchor-links-in-twitter-status-text-with-javascript/) that worked well for me. Just run the Twitter 'text' property through it:

```
// Convert URLs (w/ or w/o protocol), @mentions, and #hashtags into anchor links
function twitterLinks(text)
{
    var base_url = 'http://twitter.com/';   // identica: 'http://identi.ca/'
    var hashtag_part = 'search?q=#';        // identica: 'tag/'
    // convert URLs into links
    text = text.replace(
        /(>|<a[^<>]+href=['"])?(https?:\/\/([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,5}(\/[-a-z0-9!#()\/?&.,]*[^ !#?().,])?)/gi,
        function($0, $1, $2) {
            return ($1 ? $0 : '<a href="' + $2 + '" target="_blank">' + $2 + '</a>');
        });
    // convert protocol-less URLs into links        
    text = text.replace(
        /(:\/\/|>)?\b(([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,5}(\/[-a-z0-9!#()\/?&.]*[^ !#?().,])?)/gi,
        function($0, $1, $2) {
            return ($1 ? $0 : '<a href="http://' + $2 + '">' + $2 + '</a>');
        });
    // convert @mentions into follow links
    text = text.replace(
        /(:\/\/|>)?(@([_a-z0-9\-]+))/gi,
        function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
            return ($1 ? $0 : '<a href="' + base_url + $3
                + '" title="Follow ' + $3 + '" target="_blank">@' + $3
                + '</a>');
        });
    // convert #hashtags into tag search links
    text = text.replace(
        /(:\/\/[^ <]*|>)?(\#([_a-z0-9\-]+))/gi,
        function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
            return ($1 ? $0 : '<a href="' + base_url + hashtag_part + $3
                + '" title="Search tag: ' + $3 + '" target="_blank">#' + $3
                + '</a>');
        });
    return text;
}
```